# Roaming profiles stopped working on Windows 2008 R2 server after W10 anniversary update

Tags: roaming-profile

I have a network with one W2008 R2 server (AD controller) and 20 Windows10 workstations. The workstations gradually update to this year W10 (1607) - at the moment 7 of 20 are updated - and immediately after that they stop synchronize user roaming profiles with the server. After every user login onto workstation a message appears, saying that "the workstation can not synchronize with roaming profile and will use local copy of it instead" - no other messages in any log. I don't know where to start...

Comment: Any other info in the eventlog? it can be anything, like a antivirus not compatible with the anniversary upgrade. (like mcafee 8.8, the patch is not out yet last time I checked)

Comment: Still digging, but at the moment can not find anything useful... The antivirus is latest ESET Endpoint Security on workstations, and ESET File Security on server.

Comment: OK, found it. There was a problem with new profile folders - W10 Anniversary Update uses 'user.v6' folder instead of 'user.v5'. But even with this not all user profiles update properly

Answer (score 0):

All profiles have updated, after some days. So the problem was only because of lack of properly accessible 'user.v6' folders.